# Can't get google orgchart selection in Angular2

Tags: charts, google-visualization, orgchart

My code looks like:

```
drawGraph() {
  let theChart;
  let handler = () => {
    let sel = theChart.getChart().getSelection();
    alert('selection occurred');
    console.log('selection event', sel, Object.keys(sel));
  };

  this.google = this.getGoogle();
  this.dataTable = this.getDataTable();
  this.orgData.fillDataTable(this.dataTable, 'PALA,SRINIVASRAO');
  console.log('data', this.dataTable);
  this.dataTable.setRowProperty(1, 'style', 'border: 0');
  this.chart = this.createWrapped('OrgChart', 'chartDiv', this.dataTable);
  theChart = this.chart;
  this.chart.draw();
  this.google.visualization.events.addListener(this.chart, 'select', handler);
}
```

The chart draws fine, My evert handler gets hit but the getSelection() only returns ["0"].  By the way the createWrapped is using google.visualization.ChartWrapper.

So what am I doing wrong?  Besides trying to get this to work under TypeScript I mean. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getSelection()` is a *Chart* method, not a *ChartWrapper* method

instead...

`this.chart.getChart().getSelection()`

Comment: Thanks.  I figured that out and got busy in my happiness of having it working.  Hence I forgot to update here.